# 2 vms/apache servers, 2 domains and 1 ip

Tags: apache, virtual-machine, proxmox

So I have a server running proxmox with 2 vms (2 local IPs), each vm has apache server running, I need to setup 2 domains (one to each virtual machine) and I can't find a way.
Apache vhost documentation didn't help neither did google.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a haproxy cluster with one virtual IP and put back  your two apache nodes

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try it out but meanwhile I managed fix the issue with virtualhost Conf and htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Nginx Proxy Manager](https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager) (NPM) and setup proxy to 2+ (unlimited) local VMs with different domain. NPM supports web UI so it's easier to config.

The best way is create another VM which for setup NPM then you're good to go. Using this for 10+ domain and had no complaint about it.

P/s: I'm not the author of this useful app.

[image]